# Purpose of linked file vs class project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

What is the purpose of "Linked" Files in visual studio, and when I would use them versus simply including the class project that contains the file to my current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project + Add Existing Item, arrow on the Add button, select "Add as Link".

Visual Studio strongly favors *copying* the item you select in this dialog into your project directory.  This will keep you out of trouble, like accidentally modifying a source code file or resource that's also used in another project.  Or forgetting to check-in the file into source control, by far the most dangerous mishap.  Something you'll discover only a year or more from now, far too late to do anything about it.

The `Add as Link` option overrides that behavior, the file stays in its original location and the project file records the relative path of the file.

Good reasons to use this feature are *very* hard to come by.  Trying to come up with some:

- You may want to maintain a single source code file that's included in multiple projects, using Add as Link ensures you'll only ever edit that one single source file.
- You may have a project that uses the same source code files as another project but with very different build settings, in which case you'd make all of the project items a link.
- You may have a humongous resource that you don't want to have copied repeatedly in multiple projects
- You may have a deployable item, like an unmanaged DLL, that you keep in a single directory but is used in multiple unrelated projects.

Digging yourself a deep source control hole is a high risk, be sure to think this through before you commit to using the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Linked files are for when you want the code to be included in that project assembly.

*"Wow Jimmy, thanks for pointing out the obvious.  But why would I want to do this?"*

Well, there can be several reasons, but for now I'll just list one example.  Consider the scenario that your company|team requires every assembly to have certain constants or assembly attributes defined.  Instead of creating a duplicate class in every single project, you could just have one copy of the file and link it into each project.  Update the file once, and every assembly gets the changes.

Comment: -1: I think that's a case for a class library, not a linked file.

Comment: @JohnSaunders how would a class library allow you to set assembly attributes?  That has to happen at compile time.

Comment: That was for constant. For assembly attributes, you're right. But that's a very small use case.